# Changing a default date in a table to previous date if time is before 4am

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a table where the date is set as a default value so employees do not have to enter it every time they put in a new record.

The current day does not end at midnight, it ends at 4am. I am trying to change an Excel data entry set over to Access.

The function in Excel:

```
=IF(TIME(HOUR(NOW()),MINUTE(NOW()),SEC(NOW()))<=TIME(4,0,0),TODAY()-1,TODAY())
```

I get the following error:

> The expression you entered has a function containing the wrong number of arguments.

I need something similar to go into the default value for date so the new records show the correct dates.

I am able to put `Now()` or `Now()-1` there, but neither work for what I am trying to do.

Comment: Try this: `=IIf(Time()<=TimeSerial(16,0,0),DateAdd("y",-1,Now()),Now())`

Answer (score 1):

You can "offset" the date by four hours:

```
=DateValue(DateAdd("h",-4,Now()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(NOW()-TODAY()<=TIME(4,0,0),TODAY()-1,TODAY())
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
=iif(hour(now)<4,date-1,date)
```